# In Cocoa (or maybe GUI development in general) how do you specify an arbitrary number of things tiled together?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, tiling

I'm new to creating GUI's, everything I've done up until this point is using the command line.

I'm trying to create a port of minesweeper to the macintosh, as an experiment, and I've got the CLI working, but I'm running into walls everywhere with the gui. The first thing it seems I have to do, however, is be able to tile n x m 'boxes' for grid - and I'm not sure how to do that. The information is ready to be handed to it, but I don't know where to do it, or how.

Also, if anyone has any recommendations for sites/Cocoa development books, feel free to drop them in here...

Thanks!

Comment: You can always build an m x n matrix; each element representing an absolute position of a box; and then on application load, iterate the matrix, and create a new box at each position defined by the elements of the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

In general you should go with controls that give you a grid layout. Cocoa gives you two choices:

- [`NSMatrix`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html), grouping `NSCell` instances
- [`NSCollectionView`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html), grouping `NSView` instances (OSX >= 10.5)

Comment: I would use an NSMatrix of NSButtonCells in the bevel button style.